# Clean np array of NaN while deleting entries in other array accordingly

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, nan, idioms, mean-square-error

I have two numpy arrays, one of which contains about 1% NaNs.

```
a = np.array([-2,5,nan,6])
b = np.array([2,3,1,0])
```

I'd like to compute the mean squared error of `a` and `b` using `sklearn`'s [`mean_squared_error`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html).

So my question is, what's the pythonic way of removing all NaNs from `a` while at the same time deleting all corresponding entries from `b` as efficiently as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use vanilla NumPy's [`np.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) for this purpose:

```
In [136]: np.nanmean((a-b)**2)
Out[136]: 18.666666666666668
```

If this didn't exist, or you really wanted to use the `sklearn` method, you could create a [mask](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) to index the NaNs:

```
In [148]: mask = ~np.isnan(a)

In [149]: mean_squared_error(a[mask], b[mask])
Out[149]: 18.666666666666668
```

Comment: Both solutions work great. And thanks for introducing me to masking!